# Windows CMD rename *.js.gz to *.js

Tags: windows, cmd, batch-rename

I'm trying to rename **all** files in a folder with an extension of `.js.gz` to `.js`.

I have tried using the windows command [ren](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ren) like so:

```
ren *.js.gz *.js
```

This would seem like a simple thing to do through the command line but it doesn't produce the required output.

What it does end up doing is renaming `exampleFile.js.gz` to `example.js.js`

I'm sure i'd be able to accomplish this with Powershell or by using a Grunt/Gulp task.

Is there any way to get this done by using a simple built in command?

Comment: The .gz file format is a popular compressed archive format on Unix machines, equivalent to the .zip format.  The Windows "rename" command doesn't know beans about either.  Lots of utilities around to handle it, I passed the job to Igor Pavlov for well over a decade now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the DOS command line I typed: ren "*.js.gz" "*."

For me this command dropped the '.gz' file extension. I would take backups of your files before experimenting with them, DOS can sometimes produce unexpected results. I'm using Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.665].

Comment: Sorry, I think the Stack Overflow editor dropped the asterisks from that DOS command. In the following command substitute [asterisk] for the actual character. The command should have asterisks in front of both filename patterns, like so: ren  "[asterisk[.js.gz" "[asterisk]."

Answer (score 0):

The handling of extensions can be tricky. This code uses a regex to create the new filename. When you are confident that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.js.gz' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $($_.FullName -replace '^(.*)\.js\.gz$', '$1.js') -WhatIf
    }
```